# How long do de/buffs last in Pocket Mortys?

Tags: pocket-mortys

In Pocket Mortys, there are attacks that either buff the player or de-buff the opponent, but it's unclear how long they last.

There are some cases I'm curious about - particularly what events "wipe" the buff/debuffs. E.g. does swapping out a Morty affect either of the de/buffs? Does death of an opponent's Morty affect the players buffs?

I can see some potential for strategy here if I could understand what was happening. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like Pokémon. De/buffs last as long as your encounter with a trainer, council member or Morty, and that de/buff only applies to that specific Morty. The only way to get rid of it before ending the battle is to counter the de/buff with a de/buff of your own with the same strength, same statistic, opposite direction. Happy Morty training!

Source: Years of Pokémoning, about a year of Mortying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know--this page came up when I was googling the same question--but in Pokemon you do lose your stat raises if your pokemon is swapped out... along with any ailments that aren't marked on your menu, like Confusion or a Disabled move. Forcing a buffed pokemon to swap out (with a move like Roar) is sometimes called "Pseudo-Hazing" by hardcore players for this very reason.

Point is, I'd be skeptical that the other guy who answered you has solid info on Pocket Mortys mechanics either.

Personally though, I only ever really bother with Strong Accuracy debuffs--Hypnotize, Doze, and Mouth Off--because I hate being made to miss and I always want to do to other trainers what I hate to have done to me.